# What might cause uneven diskspace utilisation between the nodes of a Cassandra cluster

Tags: cassandra, diskspace

I have a 12 node Cassandra cluster (version 3.11.4) with replication factor of 3 on all non-trivial data tables (with org.apache.cassandra.locator.SimpleStrategy) and org.apache.cassandra.db.compaction.SizeTieredCompactionStrategy.

One of my nodes is using significantly more diskspace than the others (~10GB versus ~4GB for most of the rest) despite only having the same %age "Owns" value in "nodetool status".  The SSTables on that node are just order of 100-150%% bigger than on the other nodes (there are no snapshots on this system).  Its not affecting just one table - all of the larger tables in the DB are affected (in the same proportion)

I've had a look at the SSTables to see whether any have suspiciously old dates on the files (indicating some compaction problem) on that node, but all files are relatively recent and in line with the lifetime of the data plus that of the tombstones. cassandra.yaml is identical (apart from configured IP addresses) between the nodes.

There have been no recent scaling operations on this cluster and there have been no recent network connectivity issues as far as I know.

Are there any Cassandra experts out there that could suggest what this diskspace imbalance might be and possible resolutions? I was going to try restarting Cassandra on the affected node and, if that doesn't help, an explicit "nodetool repair --full", to see if they resolved the diskspace hit, but I'm a bit worried about the elapsed time for the latter.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using *allocate_tokens_for_keyspace*? That algorithm was implemented with Cassandra 3, and helps to prevent hot-spots.

More information can be found [here](https://www.datastax.com/blog/new-token-allocation-algorithm-cassandra-30) and [here](https://thelastpickle.com/blog/2019/02/21/set-up-a-cluster-with-even-token-distribution.html)

Comment: Many thanks Carlos.  Unfortunately, we're already using that feature

Comment: have you tried `nodetool cleanup` on that node? maybe it's holding data that it doesn't need any more - perhaps from a previous expansion of the cluster.